# Visual Studio not running my Android project

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and made a new android project with **blank activity** but the issue is it does not let me debug the project whenever i click on the start button it shows this **Error** [image]

it shows an error **as** 1 failed in output window:[image]

but in the **Error List** window it says 0 Errors:[image]

what is it that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Why you use Visual Studio when you have the possibility to use by Free the Android Studio IDE?
I suggest you to Download Android Studio and work with it.

A) It's made just for the development of Android applicantions
B)All tutorials and guide (from Google and others) are with Android Studio or Eclipse.
C)It's easy to use!

Hope it's help!

Comment: bro i am working with xamarin and c#, so that is why i am using visual studio

Comment: What's your target device set to? Are you sure there is good connectivity to that device?

Comment: I think it's the error of sdk, although i am not really sure. My Application works fine when i run it in my phone, but error is in emulator never loads and a deployment failed error comes on screen! @SteveKennedy

Comment: Try recreating the virtual device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) (Android Emulator) in your machine and download any of the  virtual device from the list.  You are able to run your application in this emulator much faster than default android emulator.

Hope this helps.